# AnimatedVectorDrawable.start() зависает на некоторых устройствах

Tags: java, android, анимация, android-drawable, vector-drawable

Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой:
1. У меня есть класс Activty в котором устанавливается фон (векторная анимация):

```
private void showSplashScreenAnimation() {
    AnimatedVectorDrawable animationBackground = (AnimatedVectorDrawable) getDrawable(R.drawable.splash_screen_anim);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new CenterCropDrawable(animationBackground));
    animationBackground.start();
}
```

`new CenterCropDrawable(animationBackground)` - используется для установки `scaleType = CenterCrop` (для `Drawable`);

2. Соответственно сам класс CenterCropDrawable:

```
public class CenterCropDrawable extends Drawable {

    @NonNull
    private final Drawable target;

    public CenterCropDrawable(@NonNull Drawable target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Override
    public void setBounds(@NonNull Rect bounds) {
        super.setBounds(bounds.left, bounds.top, bounds.right, bounds.bottom);
    }

    @Override
    public void setBounds(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        final RectF sourceRect = new RectF(0, 0, target.getIntrinsicWidth(), target.getIntrinsicHeight());
        final RectF screenRect = new RectF(left, top, right, bottom);

        final Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.setRectToRect(screenRect, sourceRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);

        final Matrix inverse = new Matrix();
        matrix.invert(inverse);
        inverse.mapRect(sourceRect);

        target.setBounds(Math.round(sourceRect.left), Math.round(sourceRect.top),
                Math.round(sourceRect.right), Math.round(sourceRect.bottom));

        super.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
        canvas.clipRect(getBounds());
        target.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(@IntRange(from = 0, to = 255) int alpha) {
        target.setAlpha(alpha);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(@Nullable ColorFilter colorFilter) {
        target.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return target.getOpacity();
    }
}
```

Суть проблемы: такой код позволяет установить `scaleType` для `Drawable` и воспроизвести векторную анимацию. Это работает на большом количестве старых/новых устройств, но обнаружил проблему, что у некоторых пользователей анимация не воспроизводиться (девайс был новый API 29). Она зависает на старте воспроизведения. Если изменить код:
c
 `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new CenterCropDrawable(animationBackground));`
на
`getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(animationBackground);`
то анимация на этих устройствах начинает воспроизводиться. В чем может быть проблема?

```
defaultConfig{   
minSDKVersion 21
}
```

Буду благодарен за любую помощь!